# Why awk print in two lines?

Tags: linux, awk

```
$ cat ff
./res/values/strings.xml:1293:    <string name="sub1LineNumber">Sub1 Number :</string>
./res/values/strings.xml:1302:    <string name="xdivert_partial_set">XDivert has been set only for 1st subscription</string>
./res/values/strings.xml:1870:    <string name="set_sub_1">Subscription 1: </string>
./res/values/strings.xml:1860:    <string name="sub_1">SUB 1</string>

for f in $(cat ff |awk -F : '{print $1" +" $2}'); do echo $f; done
./res/values/strings.xml
+1293
./res/values/strings.xml
+1302
./res/values/strings.xml
+1870
./res/values/strings.xml
+1860
```

I want to print $1 and $2 in format $1 +$2 in one line, but it print above, what's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need the `for` wrapper around the `awk` command.

If you just run the `awk` command, you'll get the output you want:

```
$ cat ff | awk -F : '{print $1 " +" $2}'
./res/values/strings.xml +1293
./res/values/strings.xml +1302
./res/values/strings.xml +1870
./res/values/strings.xml +1860
```

What's happening is that the `$(...)` wrapper and the `for` loop are causing each space-separated word in your `awk` output to become a separate input to the loop. Remove the loop, and remove the problem.

Comment: @Dan You should post that as an answer.

Comment: No need to `cat` the file to `awk`. Correct syntax: `awk -F : '{print $1 " +" $2}' ff`

Comment: True enough that it's not necessary (but also debatable whether it is a preferred style; I'll leave that discussion for not-stack-overflow). In this case, I was just aiming to minimally edit the original.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` doesn't print two lines; your `echo` prints the two lines because there's a space between the file name and the line number so the `for` loop sees the file name as one value for `f` and then the line number as a second value, and so on.

You also don't need to use `cat`; `awk` can read files too.

For the shown loop body, you can write:

```
awk '{print $1 " +" $2}' ff
```

For a more general loop body, you're best off avoiding the space:

```
for f in $(awk '{print $1 "+" $2 }' ff)
do
    ...whatever...
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The delimeter for `for` is any space, so the space in the awk output will be treated as a separate value.

Instead of a for loop, you can read lines of output at a time with the `while read` construct. For example,

```
awk -F : '{print $1 " +" $2}' ff | while read f; do
  echo "$f"
done
```